# PHP/MYSQL - Inserting multiple rows using mysql_insert_id?

Tags: php, mysql

### **BACKGROUND:**

I am uploading basic client information to a database from a client form. When the client clicks "Finished" the information entered such as *(Name*, *City*, *Country* etc.) are stored in the **client_info** table.

As an alternative the client can also upload image(s) to the server. The information of these images (**image_path**, **image_name**) are then stored in another, separate table called **client_images**, which has a *Foreign Key* linked with **client_info**.

**client_info table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_info` (
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `client_city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `client_country` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10446 ;
```

**client_images table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `client_images` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image_path` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=415;
```

---

### **PROBLEM:**

I have managed to successfully upload one row to the **client_images** table. Adding more than one row results in the following **error**:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`client_images`, CONSTRAINT `client_images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client_info` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) : 1452
```

However, when I test it through the console adding multiple rows and an already existing **client_id** it works perfectly well.

Example:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO client_images (image_path, image_name, client_id) VALUES ('pathname1', 'name1', 10241);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO client_images (image_path, image_name, client_id) VALUES ('pathname2', 'name2', 10241);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO client_images (image_path, image_name, client_id) VALUES ('pathname3', 'name3', 10241);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I need to point out that I have it lined up like this:

File: **(create_article.php)**

```
insert_client_info($client_name, $client_city, $client_country);    

include('uploads.php');

?>

<?php mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

Inside **uploads.php** I have a *foreach* loop that counts how many files that are going to be uploaded and in the end of the loop I currently have a function **insert_images($image_path, $image_name);**

**FUNCTION (insert_images):**

```
function insert_images($directory_path, $image_name) {  

    global $connection;
    $client_id=mysql_insert_id();

    $query = "INSERT INTO client_images (
        image_path, image_name, client_id
    ) VALUES (
        '{$directory_path}', '{$image_name}', '{$client_id}'
    )";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if ($result) {
    // Success!
    echo "<p></p>";
    echo "Successfully uploaded the file.";
    echo "<p></p>";

} else {
    // Display error message.
    echo "<p>" . mysql_error() ." : ".mysql_errno(). "</p>";
}
return $result;
}
```

Reading other similar problems I understand that the Achilles heel is probably **mysql_insert_id()** and that somehow it uses another connection different from the first one in the *foreach* loop, thus resulting in getting the before mentioned MYSQL error.

Thanks
/
EDZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding more than one row results in the following error:

The last insert id is the one generated by the most recent INSERT in the current MySQL session that generated an auto-incrementing id.

When you insert the first image, the most recent INSERT is the one for client_info.

But once you get to the second image, the most recent INSERT is that of the first image, so the value returned by mysql_insert_id() is different.  Likewise every subsequent INSERT changes the value returned by mysql_insert_id().

You should set the variable $client_id *before* your foreach loop starts to insert images, and pass that variable to each call to insert_images().  In uploads.php:

```
$client_id=mysql_insert_id();
foreach (...) {
    insert_images($client_id, ...);
}
```

Pass $client_id as a parameter of your insert_images() function, instead of setting $client_id in the function.

```
function insert_images($client_id, $directory_path, $image_name) {  
    ...
}
```

---

P.S.: @tttony has a good point when he reminds you to be careful about SQL injection.

See also my presentation [SQL Injection Myths and Fallacies](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies), or the chapter on SQL injection in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Answer (score 1):

this part:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO client_images (
        image_path, image_name, client_id
    ) VALUES (
        '{$directory_path}', '{$image_name}', '{$client_id}'
    )";
```

Would be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO client_images (
        image_path, image_name, client_id
    ) VALUES (
        '$directory_path', '$image_name', $client_id
    )";
```

You must escape the variables with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Also `$client_id` is numeric so does not need to quote `'$client_id'`

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this, it is only an example. But thanks anyways.